# Vertically align elements throughout the entire screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have mobile screen that look like this:[image]

I want all the icons of the phone to be aligned so that they stand below each other.

I use grid system of bootstrap.

How can iI do this?

Comment: show some code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is using grid system, for example you can do something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">ICON1</div>
    <div class="col-10">TEXT1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">ICON2</div>
    <div class="col-10">TEXT2</div>
</div>
```